# What are collinear mass, visible mass, effective mass, and invariant mass?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, terminology

What are collinear mass, visible mass, [effective mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass), and [invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass)? These terms appear quite frequently in particle physics papers but I did not find any resource where these terms are properly defined and distinguished. Can somebody help me with this or redirect me to a resource?

For example, see the following plot:
[image]

Comment: More on different masses: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8610/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic The question is not related to the link you gave. I am asking a completely different concept.

Comment: this summary might inerest you https://indico.cern.ch/event/178964/contributions/1446557/attachments/235823/330011/massReco.pdf