# How does a particle of light reach the max speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a photon have no mass and still travel at the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/how-can-a-photon-have-no-mass-and-still-travel-at-the-speed-of-light)

First of all I am not a professional physicist. I was curious as to how a particle of light can reach the maximum speed of light c given that particles experience an increase in mass as they approach c ?

Answer (score 14):

A [photon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon) does not "reach" light speed, it is "born" with 
that velocity. 
And because the photon has no rest mass, there is no problem 
inherent.