# Why don't we substitute for $p$ in $E = pc$?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light, momentum

See, the energy of a photon is given out by $E = pc = hv$ why don't we substitute for $p$ in $E ^2= p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4$ by putting $p = \gamma mv$ and then get a value for $m$ (which will be $0$ for a photon) and therefore rendering the equation to $E = 0$. I am just getting a bit confused.

**EDIT**

Since, $p= \frac{E}{c}$ can we conclude that the momentum for red light will be lesser than that for blue light as red light has less $E$ ?

Comment: You cannot conclude that $p=0$ because $m=0$. Notice that $\gamma\rightarrow\infty$ for $v\rightarrow c$. Therefore, $m\gamma$ is undetermined.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3541/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> by putting $p=\gamma mv$ and then get a value for $m$ (which will be 0 for a
>   photon) and therefore rendering the equation to $E=0$

First, let's write this out in full (in 1D)

$$p = \frac{m v}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$

Then, solve for $m$

$$m = p\frac{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}{v}$$

Now, **holding $p$ constant**, see that the limit of $m$ as $v \rightarrow c$ is zero

$$\lim_{v \rightarrow c}m = 0$$

So, a massless particle *can* have non-zero momentum and thus, non-zero $E$ when $v = c$.

Comment: Nice answer but according to the statement that "a massless particle can have non-zero momentum", won't it contradict the equation $p =\gamma mv$ itself. It will state that the momentum does not even depend on mass.

Comment: @rahulgarg12342, I don't see a contradiction.  If the invariant mass is non-zero, the momentum is proportional to the invariant mass.  If the invariant mass is zero, the four-momentum is null, and the (three-) momentum is proportional to the energy.

Comment: Please answer the question after edit.

Comment: @rahulgarg12342, the momentum for a *photon* is $p = \frac{E}{c} = \frac{h\nu}{c} = \frac{h}{\lambda}$ so *yes*, a photon of red light will have less momentum than a photon of blue light.

Comment: This is the last of my doubts. Please also tell me that why do we have to make $m$ the subject in the equation. Is there a direct logical explanation for why shouldn't $p$ be affected by zero mass. Because if we put $m = 0$ in $p = \gamma mv$ then we directly get $p = 0$ but why not otherwise. It is the same equation.

Comment: @rahulgarg12342, as others have mentioned, setting the invariant mass $m=0$ gives $p=0$ for any $v < c$.  However, if $v = c$, $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ is not defined thus, the equation $p = \gamma m v$ cannot be applied for the case $m=0, v=c$.  However, one can rearrange the equation as I did and see that, in fact, $p$ can be *non-zero* for the case $m=0, v=c$

Comment: @rahulgarg12342 what Alfred is doing is looking at the limit as $v\rightarrow c$. We see that $m$ tends to zero as you approach $v=c$. This is some information that you can't extract by simply putting $v=c$ in blindly.

Answer (score 6):

That's because the relation $p=\gamma mv$ doesn't hold universally. As you just showed yourself, using this relation for a photon would lead to a contradiction because the energy of a photon isn't zero.

A heuristic way of seeing why this relation won't hold for a photon is by recognizing that $$p=\gamma mv =m\frac{d x}{d\tau}$$
but a photon doesn't experience any proper time, so it wouldn't seem like a sensible idea to proceed in this fashion.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that $\gamma\to\infty$ as $v\to c$.

Answer (score 5):

You can understand the expression by attempting the limit for $v\rightarrow c$ and $m\rightarrow0$. Notice that $\gamma\rightarrow\infty$ when $v\rightarrow c$. Therefore $m v \gamma$ is an undetermination of the form $0\cdot\infty$. From your expressions, you cannot say that $E=0$. The limit does not exist, and this implies that this expression is not valid for a massless particle.

Actually, if I can go a bit further, you can wonder what would happen if we relax one of the two properties: being massless and travelling at $c$. If the particle is not massless, then $E=m c^2 \gamma$ enforces the fact that it cannot travel at $v=c$, or otherwise $\gamma\rightarrow\infty$ and the particle would have infinite energy. Also, if it does not travel at $v=c$, then it cannot be massless, or otherwise it would not have energy. The conclusion of this would be that only massless particles can travel at $v=c$, and particles that travel at $v=c$ must be necessarily massless. In other words, a particle is massless if and only if it travels at $v=c$, which is actually a fact.