# How can individual photons have different amounts of energy?

Tags: mass, speed-of-light, mass-energy

If photon is an elementary particle, how can different photons have different energy, if [$E=mc^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) and all photons have (or don't have) the same mass and the speed of photon is constant shouldn't it mean all photons have the same amount of energy?

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3541/, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Not only can individual photons have different energies, the *same* photon has different energies since *energy is reference frame dependent*.  A photon with a certain energy in a frame of reference will have a different energy in a different frame of reference.  Relatively moving observers will not agree on the energy of the same photon.

Comment: This question (v2) seems spurred by a confusion between rest/invariant mass and relativistic mass. See e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8610/2451) Phys.SE post, and a couple of paragraphs down on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 9):

$E = mc^2$ is only true for particles at rest (momentum $p = 0$). The full formula is $$E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2}$$.

In these formulas, $m$ is the rest mass (or just "mass"). Photons don't have mass, so for them the formula becomes $E = pc = \frac{hc}{\lambda} = h\nu$ where $\nu$ is the frequency.

Therefore, the energy of a photon is proportional to its frequency.

Answer (score 7):

I know that everyone recognizes $E = mc^2$ as the emblem of relativity, but the expressions is either incomplete or only applies to massive particles (depending on how you understand the $m$ that appears there).

The full and complete expression is
$$ (mc^2)^2 = E^2 - (pc)^2 \,,$$
where $m$ should be understood to be the invariant rest mass.

This allows you to recover either interpretation of the shorter form for massive particles and $E = pc$ for massless particles.

Comment: This is the better way to write the equality because it shows that the mass is the square of the energy-momentum 4-vector and therefore invariant.

Comment: ...although that is completely lost on anyone who actually needs to look up the answer to this question ;)